# How do I Update the value of a Characteristic from a Homebridge Plugin?

Tags: node.js, homekit

I have a plugin for Homebridge that operates shades, i.e. WindowCovering Services. It basically imitates the remote for the shades. The remote has 16 channels and one of them, 0, operates all shades. Each shade/channel is an Accessory on a Dynamic Platform. As the shades move I am updating the CurrentPosition and PositionState Characteristics. This seems to work fine now. However, some updates never seem to reach Homekit.

When multiple shade/channels are moving at the same time, this shows in the Home app as "Opening" or "Closing". When the PositionState is updated to Stopped, the icons show the current %age open. However the updates on some shades will get lost.

I thought perhaps a delay between update calls is required, so I implemented a scheme that prevents calls being made close together with a configurable delay. That seemed to improve things, but updates are still lost and I don't really know if the delay is required.

All PositionState updates go through this code. I have been debugging this issue for quite a while and am convinced the code is executed, but I can't figure out why the Home app does not see the Stop.

```
  updateStateCB() {
    this.service.getCharacteristic(this.platform.Characteristic.PositionState).updateValue(this.positionState);
    this.logTimeCh('Update state:' + this.positionState);
  }
```

Where might I be going wrong here? Is the delay between calls required? Is there a bug in Homekit somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: What does "However the updates on some shades will get lost." mean? The updates of the CurrentPosition or PositionState or any of them. Does the Home app recognize the changes after restarting the app or your iPhone?

Comment: The updates might happen at the end of a shade movement for example. If the movement is in the "group", ie all shades, then several updates are fired off at the same time. I put in code to delay updates for a configurable amount of milliseconds and the problem no seems to have gone away. The queuing code is in the platform and shared by all the shade accessories so the queuing is coordinated. With no queuing later updates would succeed.